# Networkx weights meaning for centrality & communities

Tags: networkx, social-networking, directed-graph, weighted-graph, node-centrality

I am building a directed graph with weights, where the higher the weight, the more "connected" the nodes are (in my use case weight is the sum of interactions between 2 nodes).
I am using Networkx to model the graph and to compute 2 things:

1. communities
2. most influential node in each community
   for this, I use **louvain_communities** for communities detection, and multiple centrality metrics, which I compare (closeness_centrality, betweenness_centrality, eigenvector_centrality, pagerank)

My question is:
For each of these metrics\algorithms (i.e., `louvain` and all of the centrality metrics), is the weight means "distance" or "closeness"?
Should I use `weight=weight` or `weight=1/weight`?

I tried to read the documentation but its quite confusing